# google spreadsheet display all values in a column but replace value if number

Tags: google-sheets

In column A I have a list of values that can be numbers or text, for example:

```
Green
3498784
Blue
Yellow
3985390
Red
```

I would like to display (mirror) these values in column B, but only display the 'text' values. The cells with numbers should be empty.

So column B would look like this:

```
Green

Blue
Yellow

Red
```

How to accomplish this using ARRAYFORMULA?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this answer?

#### Sample formula 1:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(TO_TEXT(A1:A),"^\d+$", ""))
```

- In this case, I used `REGEXREPLACE` for checking whether the value is the number.

#### Sample formula 2:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISNUMBER(A1:A),"",A1:A))
```

- In this case, I used `ISNUMBER` for checking whether the value is the number.

#### Result:

This is a sample result of Sample formula 1.

[image]

#### References:

- [REGEXREPLACE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098245)
- [ISNUMBER](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093296)